# Running a Linux-based distribution on a Samsung Chromebook

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chromebook

Is it possible to run a Linux-based distribution, e.g. Ubuntu on a Samsung Chromebook alongside the Chrome OS?

If so, is the installation process of Ubuntu any different from installing on a regular Windows 7/8 laptop, and how would I carry out the install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible. There is actually a special build of Ubuntu for the Samsung ARM chromebook called Chrubuntu. This looks like a pretty good writeup: http://www.amirkurtovic.com/blog/installing-chrubuntu-on-the-samsung-arm-chromebook-a-step-by-step-photo-guide/

Comment: That does look promising. I was told it could well be possible because the Samsung Chromebook is essentially a Linux laptop. I think this should further increase the appeal of the chromebook especially to linux users.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton), which I preferred after trying Chrubuntu.